# Displayed stock status on WooCommerce custom product type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, stock

I've created custom product type called "event". On product page I would like to display custom stock status, so I use this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'yy',  15 );
function yy() {
  global $post;
    if( function_exists('get_product') ){
      $product = get_product( $post->ID );
        if( $product->is_type( 'event' ) ){
          if ( $product->stock ) { // if manage stock is enabled 
            if ( number_format( $product->stock,0,'','' ) > 0 ) { // if stock is low
              echo '<p class="stock in-stock">' . number_format($product->stock,0,'','') . ' in stock</p>';
              } elseif ( number_format( $product->stock,0,'','' ) == 0 ) {
              echo '<p class="stock out-of-stock">' . __('Out of stock', 'behold-basic') . '</p>'; 
              }
        }
    };
  }
}
```

but when stock is 0 nothing is showing up, should be "Out of stock". Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is completely outdated since WooCommerce 3… Now you should try to use [`WC_Product` methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) related to stock instead *(if your custom product type extends `WC_Product` Class  as it should be)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'before_add_to_cart_form_callback',  15 );
function before_add_to_cart_form_callback() {
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type( 'event' ) ){
        if ( $product->get_manage_stock() ) { // if manage stock is enabled
            $stock  = (int) $product->get_stock_quantity();
            $status = $product->get_stock_status();

            if ( $stock > 0 ) { // if stock is low
                echo '<p class="stock in-stock">' . $stock . ' ' . __('in stock', 'behold-basic') ; '</p>';
            } elseif ( $stock == 0 ) {
                echo '<p class="stock out-of-stock">' . __('Out of stock', 'behold-basic') . '</p>'; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should better work…

Comment: Great, works! Yes, my custom products type extends WC_Product. Big thanks!

Comment: @Damian An oversight: I have made a little update in the `elseif` condition…